# Receiving INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR REST API

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

Using REST API, sandbox and attempting to get bearer token. Receiving the following error

{"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","information_link":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"5a235c510522b"}

How can I find out what the debug id means?

Answer (score 3):

The 'debug_id' is an internal identifier we can use to pull up the request within PayPal.
You may see our classic API calls refer to this as the 'correlationID'.

Unfortunately I'm not finding anything in our system for this debug_id. Can you log a ticket (www.paypal.com/mts) or email me (address in profile) with details of the call, including your full HTTP request (minus credentials) and the resources you tried to access, as well as the full HTTP response?

I suggest we close this answer as it's not strictly programming-related, but I can continue working on this via mail / ticket with you.

By the way; if you're using the 4111111111111111 credit card: this card number is currently inoperable in the Sandbox environment and may throw 'internal service error' type responses as well. You can use any other card number instead.

Comment: The Visa test credit card number of 4111111111111111 still throws "Internal Service Error" - wish that was *documented* before I wasted a good hour thinking it was my side of the fence and not the sandbox.