# Rest PayPal API Internal Service Error

Tags: paypal

Were getting a lot of #INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR's through the rest PayPal API. To get more details about the error we have been going the PayPal Tech Support. We've been able to fix some of the issues but it is taking us a lot longer than we would like. I was wondering if there was an API call that I could make that would give me the full details of the error or DebugID?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how you are currently consuming the API, but https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/ specs the error object which has the debug_id, the PayPal internal identifier used for correlation purposes. The error object has information link and error_details object which has the detailed reasons for the error

If you are using an sdk to consume, it is possible to get the debug_id in your logs: https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-nodejs#debugging and https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sdk-python#create-payment show ways to do that in Python and Node.

Answer (score 0):

I myself am looking for the same information. But it appears the debug ID is only so Paypal support can correlate the error to a transaction event. Technically there is no other information associated with the Debug ID.

See [Receiving INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17839960/receiving-internal-service-error-rest-api)